# How to make the contend to be equal with the body

Tags: css, html

I am struggling with a problem for my website.

I would like to make the `<div id="content" >` to be equal with the body which have the width `960px`. what is wrong or missing in my code? Sorry i cant post the code directly here, is not allowing me. Here is the link with my files:

https://github.com/gabrielniculita/Project-portofoliu.git

Comment: Can you provide a codepen with your code so that we can see it live? 
If you know that your body will have a width of 960, you can set the height to 960. If you need this to be responsive, you might be able to use height: 100vw  (vw = viewport width), or min-height if you want to be able to have bigger stuff as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, write CSS for id '#content' and class '.Project1' like below:

```
#content {
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Project1 {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

And also additionally, you can center your body element by writing the CSS like below:

```
body {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
```